# Can Tongue and Groove plywood be used if interior walls already in place

Tags: flooring

can Tongue and Groove plywood be used for installing a new sub-floor when there are walls already in place? (i.e. an existing home in use, not a new construction)

In other words: I've been told that T&G can only be used IF walls are not already in existence. Such as building a new home OR removal of all interior walls first, such as in a major re-model job.

But I just want to replace a bedroom floor area in a home with walls still in place.

As I re-read the comments, I'm seeing that everyone is referring to the actual top layer of flooring you walk on. I'm not talking about that at all. I'm talking about adding new "sub" flooring over the floor joists T&G "plywood sheathing".

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  I have no idea why someone would say that.

Comment: Exactly. Why *wouldn't* you be able to use it?

Comment: @Paulster2 - no idea.  Maybe someone installs it floating and nails down portion under the walls... I am just reaching but no clue.  And obviously you don't float your subfloor.

Comment: I guess the reason they are saying this, is that it would be really difficult to connect them together where a wall comes into play. How do you tuck the plywood when you are at a corner of the room? And also when installing the final piece. I can't find one source on internet that talks about (or shows in a video) how you can lay down T&G in a room with 4 walls. anyone know a source online to review on this?

Comment: You just cut out the T/G and nail it down.  You are making this too hard.

Comment: ... and cover the transition with shoe molding.

Comment: I guess I"m not explaining my issue clearly. I see T&G like puzzle pieces. If you start at one wall on left of room, you can tuck it under for sure, and work your way over to the right wall. But you eventually you run out of workspace to manuever the pieces into place and can't get enough of the plywood under the right side wall where you are trying to lay the final row. I don't think I'm able to explain without visuals. I wish there was a video I could see that showed someone laying T&G in a small room....

Comment: I should also add, I"m talking about installing a SUB-FLOOR. I"m not referring to a top finish of pretty floor planks that use T&G pieces. I also realize that maybe I just need to add regular plywood under the walls and then use T&G UP TO the walls instead of trying to get the pieces UNDER the wall areas. Hmmmm....

Comment: @user37241 like DMoore says, you just cut off the bottom of the groove (or tongue) for the last piece you install, and nail it down. Most of the conversation here is giving you directions on the subfloor. As for what to do under the walls, that's a different question and should be asked separately.

Comment: My answer was for subfloor.  Which you really don't have to have perfectly tucked to wall in most cases.

Comment: Thanks everyone. that makes sense to me. Im going to have to see why this other person told me otherwise...

Comment: Because they don't understand what they are talking about or you misunderstood them.  This isn't a complicated thing.